# How to deep copy an object array of multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy

As the title suggest, how do I do that? I have searched everywhere in the internet, maybe I didn't search for the right word or something. But please help me.

```java
Object[] FlyingObject = new FlyingObject[3];
FlyingObject[0] = new Helicopter();
FlyingObject[1] = new Airplane();
FlyingObject[2] = new Drone();

Public static Object[] CopyFlyingObject(Object[] C){
    Object FlyingObjectCopy = new Object(C.length);
    // ...I got no idea how to continue from here
}
```

Using `clone()` is not allowed and you aren't allowed to find the name of the class either. I have copy constructor in my other classes but I have no idea how to call it when we're using object, especially with an object array with unknown classes throughout the array.

Edit:
My Subclass code

```
'''java
    int speed;
    double price;
    Helicopter(){
         speed = 0;
         price = 0.0;
    }
    Helicopter(Helicopter c){
         speed = c.speed;
         price = c.price; 
    }

    public Airplane extends Helicopter{
      String brand;   
      Airplane(){
         super();
         brand = "";
       }
      Airplane(Airplane c){
         super(C);
         brand = c.brand;
       }
      public String getBrand(){
         return brand;
       }
    }
    public Drone{
    //practically the same for here
    }
'''
```

Comment: Are you allowed to declare a copy method on the FlyingObject interface? You know that all the objects implement that interface, so you can call a method on it for each of them.

Comment: It did not specify that copy method aren't allowed. How can you use the copy method? The question want us to use Copy constructor that we have created in our classes. Maybe I shouldn't use object array at all but I have no idea

Comment: You should include the code for your concrete subclasses showing the copy constructor that you want to use.

Comment: I guess you could find the copy constructor reflectively and call it, if the point of the exercise is to teach you about reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited and show you the code of my subclasses. There's nothing fancy about subclasses, I still have no idea how to call copy constructor using object array with different types of classes.

Comment: I would put a copy method on the FlyingObject interface, and implement it in each subclass using your copy constructors, or you could reflectively find the copy constructor. Ask your instructor which they'd prefer.

Comment: I think what my instructor want is to use copy constructor, how do I do that?

Comment: As I said: "I would put a copy method on the FlyingObject interface, and implement it in each subclass using your copy constructors, or you could reflectively find the copy constructor" either way you are using the copy constructor.

Comment: Can you show me a method using copy constructor? I definitely know that is Drone A = new Drone();  But how do I know which class is which?